# Data stored as string, how to parse?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large txt file containing data structured as follows:

```
[(b'1', 0.979110598564148, (85.21258544921875, 299.8061828613281, 10.56136417388916, 9.491233825683594)), (b'1', 0.9736520051956177, (257.89324951171875, 35.39741897583008, 10.733377456665039, 13.221137046813965))]
```

normally id split using the comas, or brackets but in this case that would destroy the structure and make the data lose value.

can anyone recommend any methods to use for me to structure the data better.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the following: 1) Expected output of parsing...  2) What you've tried so far

Comment: At first I thougth heey that is json. Python has great support in the standard library for json, I you write the the large txt file, perhaps you can create it in json format and than it is easily loaded via the json module.

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) built-in module

```
import ast
txt = "[(b'1', 0.979110598564148, (85.21258544921875, 299.8061828613281, 10.56136417388916, 9.491233825683594)), (b'1', 0.9736520051956177, (257.89324951171875, 35.39741897583008, 10.733377456665039, 13.221137046813965))]"
data = ast.literal_eval(txt)
print(data[0])
print(data[0][0])
```

output

```
(b'1', 0.979110598564148, (85.21258544921875, 299.8061828613281, 10.56136417388916, 9.491233825683594))
b'1'
```